# Cannot change Parent Link from Userstory to another Epic

Tags: azure-devops

I have imported work items from jira to Azure DevOps. There are Epics containing user stories as children.
These links describes most of the structure of my project. The user story ha a parent link to its epic. Now, i want to change some parent links from the old epic to another epic. If i try that on the user story item, i can only choose features as new parents, but no epics.
The company has set up the "agile" process.
I already checked the devops documentation and think, that parent child links are suitable for any work item type?

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: It works as a glance. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to change some parent links from the old epic to another epic.

Open the User Story->click the links tab->Select the parent link->click the button Remove link->click Add links->Existing item->select Links type Parent->enter another Epic work item ID->Click OK and Save&Close button to save it, then we could see the parent link has changed. Check the GIF below.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Teimo, If this answer is helpful, would you please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)